# Facebook Tab App Doesn't work in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

I created a Facebook "Tab App" that appears to be working in Chrome, Safari and FireFox but doesn't seem to load at all in IE8 (and older).

Here is the link to the tab on Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/lapalomaacademy/app_190322544333196

I also uploaded the code to a page outside of Facebook, and IE8 seems to load that page fine (you can also view the source code on this page):
http://lpatucson.org/facebook/nonfans.html

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Call the HTTPS version in your IE, and you should see an error message regarding your SSL certificate: https://lpatucson.org/facebook/nonfans.html And notice how IE displays it quite well if your accessing Facebook via HTTP, http://www.facebook.com/lapalomaacademy/app_190322544333196 (disable secure browsing in your FB settings if you get redirected to the HTTPS version automatically, or view this link when not logged in.)

Comment: Oh, and my other browser’s complain about the certificate as well. (Maybe you’ve added an exception for it in yours once, so you don’t notice it.)